# Make tags [mapping] and [read mapping] synonyms

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The topic of read mapping is a sufficiently distinct subset of the more general class of sequence alignment topics to warrant a dedicated tag. However, we should collapse `mapping` and `read-mapping` as synonyms.

Comment: Mapping has distinct meaning in other subfields (e.g. family tree mapping and disease mapping). For clarity, we should not use "mapping" just for "read-mapping".

Comment: Similarly, "mapping" is used often with "QTL mapping".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, having both [mapping](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mapping) and [read-mapping](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/read-mapping) for the same thing doesn't make sense. However, instead of making them synonyms, I would suggest we only keep [read-mapping](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/read-mapping) and get rid of [mapping](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mapping) altogether.

In general, tags whose meaning isn't clear from the tag are bad tags. In fact, [mapping](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mapping) is a classic example of a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/). Briefly, meta tags are those that:

> 1. If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a
>      meta-tag. Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as
>      the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like [beginner], [subjective],
>      and [best-practices], are useless by themselves — they tell you
>      nothing at all about the content of the question.
> 2. If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s
>      probably a meta-tag. In a cruel, ironic twist, the meaning of the tag
>      [subjective] itself … is actually subjective. Ditto for
>      [best-practices] and [beginner]. Best practices to whom? Beginner by
>      what criteria? These tags are impossible to define by anything
>      remotely resembling an objective metric. In comparison, the the
>      meaning of tags like [java], [c#], and [javascript] are crystal clear
>      to all but the nuttiest of nutbags.

As user172818 [pointed out](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74/make-tags-mapping-and-read-mapping-synonyms#comment183_74) in the comments, the term "mapping" has different meanings in different subfields. Therefore, "mapping" by itself doesn't tell us anything useful about the question; it needs to be combined with another tag ([ngs](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ngs), [reads](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reads) or whatever) in order to be informative. Therefore, it is not a useful tag and should just be removed.

The simplest way to remove tags is to just edit the questions that have them. If no questions are tagged with a given tag, the tag will be deleted from the system automatically. If, in future, we see the tag returning, we can ask for it to be blacklisted.

---

Since there were only 6 or so questions tagged with [mapping](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mapping), I went through them retagged those that were about [read-mapping](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/read-mapping) accordingly. However, this question:

[probeset to probeset mappings between Affymetrix arrays](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/118/probeset-to-probeset-mappings-between-affymetrix-arrays)

is about mapping between different types of affymetrix arrays. Here, I removed [mapping](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mapping) and created a new tag [affymetrix-arrays](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/affymetrix-arrays). I don't think it would be worth creating something as specific as [affymetrix-array-mapping](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/affymetrix-array-mapping) or similar.

The others were all about [read-mapping](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/read-mapping) and are now tagged accordingly. The [mapping](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mapping) should now disappear and I suggest we let it fade into oblivion.

Comment: I thought I had added some info about the "mapping" tag, but I see that the "read-mapping" tag did not conserve this info. Or maybe I'm mistaken.

Comment: @bli oh damn! I'm sorry, that's my fault! The info wouldn't be conserved no, the `read-mapping` tag was a new tag, not a synonym so it wouldn't bring in information from elsewhere. I didn't notice you had added information to the `mapping` tag's wiki when I removed it. I hope it wasn't too much work.

Comment: I found the info back in my activity history:
"When dealing with associating sequencing reads to a matching position in a set of reference sequences (typically a genome)."
I'll add it to the "read-mapping" tag

Comment: @bli cool! Sorry for making you repeat your work, that's never fun :(

Comment: These few words were not a lot of work :)